# Why is Google Charts not showing the right data for me? Are the axis messed up?

Tags: javascript, api, graph, charts

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=600x400&chd=t:171,811,629,507,460,390,434,379,329,312,368,329,329,329,352,330,299,323,340,325,329,1895,1047,736,617,684,620,515
```

If you go there on your browser, you'll notice that you see a graph. However, the axis are messed up! And it seems like I can't see the ups and downs of my line graph. WHy?

I don't get what's wrong. I just want to plot the simple stuff on a line chart. Just those data points. Nothing more, nothing less!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use basic text format for the chart data, the range of data value is 0 - 100. Values above 100 are truncated to 100. The data values you provided are all above 100, so they are truncated to 100.

You should use [text format with custom scaling](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/data_formats.html). Try this one. The range of data values is set to 0 - 2000 using `chds=0,2000`.

`http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=600x400&chd=t:171,811,629,507,460,390,434,379,329,312,368,329,329,329,352,330,299,323,340,325,329,1895,1047,736,617,684,620,515&chds=0,2000`